Can I ask a question which is weird to interpret
In our telegram teaching group we got a question from linear algebra but I never saw such notation. If anyone knew about it please mention the name of it. I couldn't write it with any latex because not sure if its available [![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/3OhhmGlD.jpg. I have wrote what things I knew about this question. I have no further option to modify/detail and fix it. Even I can't delete it. And For this question i couldn't ask any other questions  when I tried to ask new question it said my previous question are not appropriate. I guess only 2 questions are not good for MSE even I was sure but it is a big punishment to stop learners from asking questions 

Use \overline{(a,b)} to render $\overline{(a,b)}$.

In this context, the notation $(\overline{a, b})$ most probably means the complex conjugate of a complex number, where a complex number $z = a+ib$ is being represented as $(a, b)$. The complex conjugate of $z$ is defined as $\overline{z} = a-ib$, so $(\overline{a, b}) = (a, -b)$. Therefore
\begin{equation*}
(\overline{a, b}) + (\overline{c, d}) = (a, -b) + (c, -d) = (a+c, -(b+d)) = (\overline{a+c, b+d})
\end{equation*}

The picture asks for $x-y$.

@Nothingspecial we are not here to solve such homework. OP got enough hints to do it themselves. Besides: the teacher in that group should be asked what that notation means.

@KurtG. Then the answerer could stop at $(a,b)=a+ib$. I think they intended to do the homework :/

@Nothingspecial They shouldn't. Not having solved it properly is therefore even better.

@J.Allen is this thing surely related to complex? Not in linear algebra?

if this is the notation then my answer is D no option is matching

@CiupTitu Not surely. Ask teacher.

I think you haven't read my question properly. I am organizing a telegram group of teachers where all are aspirants preparing for teaching exams so clearly there is no teacher of me. We get random weird questions and we try to solve them free of cost. And we discuss over it. This question came from a Dsssb previous year paper of teaching exam where syllabus is not defined. So everyone else is just trying their guesses. Yes. I thought also it can be conjugate symbol, other thought unitary matrix of linear algebra? But never saw such operations. Inner product space?

I don't require any solution and I only asked for hints of this symbol @KurtG.

@CiupTitu the first thing a mathematician should learn is that you can't throw a notation at someone and ask what it means. You don't even have to use Latex this time. Case closed.

This is the same situation for you. The question is asked in the DSSSB TGT teacher examination where syllabus is not defined so teaching aspirants are just analysing what is this symbol for? There is no one who can tells what does this sign mean. So I asked here. Seriously you are at high level of weird behaviour as I can see. If I know what symbol mean or If it was explained by the board in the examination why will I ask a question on MSE @KurtG.

@CiupTitu under these weird circumstances why is (d) not the correct answer?
